# Invalid cursor state in Cakephp/mssql

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, cakephp

I am connecting sql server 2008 r2 on cakephp. I need to pull the excel for which i have created the stored procedure as below

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[pullatm_card]
@date varchar(25)

as
begin
declare @sql as varchar(1000)
set @sql='INSERT INTO scts
(
terminal,
account_number,
txn_amount,
txn_date,
txn_tim,
trace_code
)

select 
f2 as terminal,
f6 as account_number,
f10 as txn_amount,
f14 as txn_date,
f22 as txn_time,
f27 as trace_code 
FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'',
                ''Excel 8.0;Database=C:\rbl\sct\'+@date+'\excel\atm\cards.xls;IMEX=1'',
                ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'')

                where f14 is not null'

exec(@sql)
```

when i fire

```
exec pullatm_card'DEC01_2013EXCEL' on sql server query editor it is running sucessfully.
```

But when i try the same in cakephp as below

```
public function admin_add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            //call three procedure here
            $date=$this->request->data['Sct']['date'];

            $this->Sct->query("exec pullatm_card"."'".$date."'");
            $this->Sct->query("exec pullatm_loro"."'".$date."'");
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('SCT record(s) been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));

            }
    }
```

It throws error as below

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[24000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid cursor state

SQL Query: exec pullatm_card'DEC01_2013EXCEL'
```

But results of exec pullatm_card'DEC01_2013EXCEL' are inserted in database and it halt all other operations after that i.e  query just below it (see php) wont be fired?

what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Go on below link this might help you.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/icc97/2011/09/25/sql_server_storedprocedure_behaviour